# How can I programmatically generate relevant tags for a database of URLs?

Tags: python, nlp, keyword, google-ads-api

I'm writing an RSS reader in python as a learning exercise, and I would really like to be able to tag individual entries with keywords for searching.  Unfortunately, most real-world feeds don't include keyword metadata.  I currently have about 60,000 entries in my test database from about 600 feeds, so manually tagging is not going to be effective.  So far I have only been able to find two solutions:

**1: Use [Natural Language Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/nltk/) to extract keywords:**

- Pros: flexible; no dependencies on external services;
- Cons: can only index the article summary, not the article; non-trivial: writing a high quality keyword extraction tool is a project in itself;

**2: Use the [Google Adwords API](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService.RelatedToUrlSearchParameter.html) to fetch keyword suggestions from the article url:**

- Pros: Super high quality keywords; based on entire article text; easy to use;
- Cons: Not free(?); Query rate limits unknown; I'm terrified of getting my account banned and not being able to run adwords campaigns for my commercial sites;

Can anyone offer any suggestions?  Are my fears about getting my adwords account banned unfounded?

Comment: Just to follow up:  I ended up using python-calais, which is a little stale (last updated in 2009) but has worked flawlessly so far.  It has a convenience function that takes a url as argument and returns a calais response parsed into a python dict.  I have been very impressed with the accuracy and relevance of the metadata provided, especially considering the cost (free).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[delicious suggested tags API](http://www.delicious.com/help/api#posts_suggest)**.

An example of how to use the api via python http://www.michael-noll.com/projects/delicious-python-api/

An other alternative is **[Open Calais](http://www.opencalais.com/)**

Comment: I was not aware of Open Calais, this looks awesome.  I have a feeling this is going to spawn quite a few new projects.  :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of free and commercial text annotation tools/services you might consider, depending on your specific needs, listed under:

[Is there a better tool than OpenCalais?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119279/is-there-a-better-tool-than-opencalais).

A number of these provide entities, some provide a measure of keyword relevance, and others provide topic tags.